# C++ Graphics in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, header-files

How can graphics functions be used in Visual Studio 2017 (C++) without using a BGI library? What header file is used? I want to use these functions to do things like drawing a circle.

Comment: Just use one of these: opengl+glut, vulkan api, direct3d, qt with some plot-plugins.

Comment: For simple stuff just use GDI.

Comment: Well, are there already present header files? I mean, does Visual Studio 2017 (c++) have a header file to perform graphics functions?

Answer (score 2):

The header file `<windows.h>` allows you to use  [Windows API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API)  for many functionalities including but not limited to functions that you will use to do graphics by yourself such as `SetPixel` and `GetPixel` and many others you can see the code in this  [repository](https://github.com/mis94/Graphtona-2D-Package/tree/master/Graphtona/Graphtona)  which contains C++ implementations for various circle drawing algorthims.

Comment: Can you create a simple game like Rapid Roll using <windows.h>?

Comment: If you mean something like the one [here](http://sindhitutorials.com/videos/c-projects/rapid-roll-game-c-language) I think it is difficult without the usage of any other libraries as `windows.h` would not help with animations, so you would need to implement everything by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, and could you also answer-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994926/why-does-a-dot-pattern-appear-on-screen-in-this-program

This is Turbo C++, but I wanna know the reason.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know nothing about Turbo C++.

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few options:

- Windows API - Quite difficult to use but runs incredibly fast. This is perhaps the most difficult option due to how complex and no-hand-holding it is.
- MFC - Microsoft's tools for C++ graphics. Not too easy to use but certainly easier than WinAPI. A lot of people don't like using this as it's kind of old and there are better stuff out there.
- OpenGL/Vulkan/DirextX - These three are very similar technologies. They are based around using your graphics card for drawing, using small programs called 'shaders' which can be edited and compiled on the fly. Most games use one of these, and they run pretty fast. DirectX is Windows only, and Vulkan is pretty low-level. I would recommend OpenGL out of these three.
- External library - There are many libraries you can use such as Qt, wxWidgets or SFML. All of these have their own pros and cons, but they all are third party libraries which bridge the gap between commands like 'draw a circle' and the Windows calls that go on under the surface.
- Chromium Embedded Framework - CEF allows you to code the guts of your program in C++, then create the GUI using HTML5 and Javascript. Essentially it's a web browser connected to a C++ backend. Looks really nice but some criticise it for its resource usage, which is much larger than the alternatives.

I would recommend staying away from WinAPI and MFC and either use a third-party library (for simple GUIs) or OpenGL (for complex rendering i.e. games). If you're confident in web programming then you can go for CEF.

Comment: Websites don't explain much, so can you please brief me about how you link HTML 5/JavaScript files to a C++ file (I am a beginner)? What kind of GUI does one create and how? Just a bit of explanation would do.

Comment: @ParamahamsanNallathambi CEF allows you to run a version of the Chromium web browser within a C++ program. Essentially it's a web browser with special JavaScript bindings that can connect to a C++ backend. The browser is also managed and controlled from the C++ program.

Comment: Thanks, and could you also answer-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994926/why-does-a-dot-pattern-appear-on-screen-in-this-program

This is Turbo C++, but I just wanna know the answer.

Comment: @ParamahamsanNallathambi I don't know anything about Turbo C++. Besides, that question has nothing to do with this one.